# Как скрыть JPopupMenu после клика мышью в другом месте окна?

Tags: java, swing

Появляется мой объект `jPopupMenu` по определенному событию, когда пользователь клацает правой кнопкой по таблице (`JTable`). Нужно его скрыть, если пользователь кликнет вне зоны самой менюшки и таблицы любой кнопкой или показать в другом месте, если пользователь кликнет правой кнопкой.

Ну показать в другом месте получилось, просто меняю location. И если уже открыт, то могу скрыть при условии что кликнули по таблице. Как скрыть, если пользователь кликну по окну приложения?

Comment: Разобрался, сейчас напишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно чтобы окно приложения наследовало класс `WindowAdapter`, нужный тебе метод:

```
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
{
...
}
```

обрабатывает события при активации окна, там и прописать что-то вроде `popupMenu.setVisible(false);` или как там у тебя устроен код.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже до этого додумался.